# Метки сомнительного качества

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

Есть список меток: http://pastebin.com/W8i3j6Sv
Из этого списка я начал выделять метки, которые можно было бы удалить или объединить:

[1с-битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) - синоним [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix), или наоборот

[3.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3.0) - сомнительная и непонятно с чем связанная

[3g](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3g) - сомнительная

[80](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/80) - сомнительная

[action](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/action) - сомнительная

[ad](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ad) - синоним [active-directory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/active-directory)

[adsl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adsl) - сомнительная

[andriod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andriod) - опечатка

[andro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andro) - выглядит как опечатка

[angularjs-2.0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) - синоним [angular2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)

[animate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animate) - синоним [animation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation)

[ar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) - неясно то ли Unix утилита, то ли что-то еще

[assembly](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) - синоним [assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler)

[astesisk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astesisk) - опечатка

[asus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asus) - сомнительная, для каждого бренда добавлять метки?

[async-programming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-programming) - синоним async?

[at](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at) - переименовать в at-command?

[attr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) - сомнительная

[attribute](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribute) - сомнительная

Список меток очень большой, есть ли смысл продолжать? И если есть, то как оформить, не плодить же вопросы?

Comment: assembly - это "сборка" в смысле "контейнер" в .net - ничего общего с ассемблером.

Comment: @PashaPash, я подумал, что assembly-language. На enSO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly именно ASM (+ синонимы assembly-language и assembler), а для .NET завели отдельную метку - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-assembly

Comment: Это понятно, но метки стоит заводить исходя из того как их расставляют люди.  Брать метку, в которой все вопросы, кроме одного, заданы про сборки, и принудительно делать ее синонимом ассемблера, только потому что на enSO так сделано - достаточно бессмысленно.

Comment: `async` и `async-programming` точно сомнительные, ведь есть красивая и понятная `асинхронность`.

Answer (score 9):

Мусора в метках с 1–10 использованиями — больше, чем пара-другая человек в силах вычистить, а больше желающих этим заниматься вы не найдёте. В общем-то цель недостижимая, потому что неправильные метки будут появляться быстрее, чем вы будете их чистить. Большой проблемы эти метки также не представляют: они висят где-то в хвосте списка меток и никого не трогают.

В принципе подобные метки можно использовать в качестве источника вопросов, которые следует подправить: если есть один недочёт, велик шанс, что есть и другие. То же верно и для свежих вопросов, особенно для популярных: имеет смысл приводить метки в порядок. Однако не стоит рассчитывать, что вы достигнете цели уничтожения всех мусорных меток.

Короче, сопротивление бесполезно. Если хотите привести именно метки в порядок, то советую отсортировать не по алфавиту по возрастанию, а по количеству вопросов по убыванию. Если более приоритетно приведение в порядок вопросов, то лучше поискать вопросы с большим количеством просмотров и/или высокой оценкой, но с очень редкими метками. В обоих случаях ваша работа будет приводить к более осязаемым результатам, потому что посетители её хотя бы увидят.

Comment: А на so есть какое-либо API, чтобы автоматом пройтись по постам и поменять? Скажем, взять посты с тегом `andriod` и заменить на правильный - `android`? Или ситуация "сапожники без сапог", программисты без API?

Comment: @AK Инструменты для переименования и слияния меток доступны участникам с рангом ромб и выше. Синонимизация меток доступна раньше, конкретные требования для голосования за синонимы где-то в справке валяются. API тоже есть, вроде, но я бы не советовал увлекаться массовыми правками без предварительного обсуждения. Очепяток обычно ничтожно мало, поэтому лучше пользоваться ручной правкой. Как я уже сказал, наличие одной проблемы — часто признак наличия нескольких, поэтому ручная правка, при которой вы видите редактируемое сообщение, предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 5):

По поводу возникновения меток 3.0, 80 и пр. - возникают они очень просто:

Кто-то берет и пишет в поле для меток: *"порт 80"* или *"python 3.0"*. Получается две метки :)

Answer (score 4):

> [3g](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3g) - сомнительная

Не сомнительная. Это тип интернет-соединения.

> [adsl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adsl) - сомнительная

Тоже...

> [assembly](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) - синоним [assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler)

Мимо. Это про сборки.

Comment: Все же 3g - это тип не интернет-соденинения, а протокол передачи данных. Совершенно не обязательно что он используется для интернет-соединения.