# Удалить метку [andriod]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

Заметил что есть метка [andriod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andriod). Так же нашел [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3251/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) которому уже 5 лет в котором эта метка упоминается. Может имеет смысл как-то удалить метку и переместить все вопросы (5 штук) в метку android?

Comment: Переметить и все дела, конечно.

Comment: а это вручную делать или есть какой-то автоматизированный механизм для таких дел?

Comment: Просто правки внести (я внес)

Comment: Вот и всё, "Нет вопросов с меткой andriod." Значит, если удалить все упоминания меток, то и сама метка удаляется.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если метка явная опечатка, вопросов мало, а у вас достаточно репутации, чтобы вносить правки, то достаточно метки просто руками поправить, даже не поднимая вопроса на Мете.